# Why is it possible to put unlimited empty bracket in functions?

Tags: c#, compilation

While programming, I realized that I can insert open bracket with close bracket anywhere in a function (even if it's not for a conditional statement / using statement / or loop,etc.).

```
    private Int32 OutsideSquare(Int32 value)
    {
        Int32 square;
        {
            square = value * value; // Compile and work!
        }
        return square;
    }

    private Int32 InsideSquare(Int32 value)
    {
        {
            Int32 square = value * value; // Doesn't compile - not in context!
        }
        return square;
    }
```

Why is this accepted by the compiler? why does "OutsideSquare" compile but not "InsideSquare" when both seems to "ignore" the brackets for the result?

Comment: Is "because Dennis Ritchie said so" a good answer? Unfortunately, he's no longer with us to give you a better answer.

Comment: I can't decide if this is idiotic or interesting?

Comment: You might want to read up on variable scope ...

Comment: It has to do with how variables are scoped in c#. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the compiler accepts arbitrary pairs of brackets inside functions, but they are not simply ignored. Brackets create scope. Any variables declared within the brackets cannot be used outside the brackets. For example, consider the following program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    {
        string s = "Hello world";
        Console.WriteLine(s);     // works fine
    }

    Console.WriteLine(s);         // error!
}
```

This second call to `Console.WriteLine(s)` will generate an error like this:

> The name 's' does not exist in the current context

Because the variable `s` was only defined within the scope of the brackets. This is the same issue you're seeing with the `InsideSquare` method. You cannot use a variable outside of the scope in which it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

> both seems to "ignore" the brackets for the result?

**NO**

it is called scope and variables declared inside the scope usng `{ }` are only accssible inside that block